# How to use seekbar[i].setmax(a)

Tags: android

I have seen in many stackoverflow answers as seekbar with index in android. How can i use it.

I used SeekBar[] s = new SeekBar[4];

But when giving id the app stops.

Can anyone help me out.

Any answers will be appreciated. :-)

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Not just a simple line. Also, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Dan Baruch    Sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

In your activity, you have 5 `SeekBar` in total, so no need to declare 5 `SeekBar` instance, instead of using an array of `SeekBar` that contains 5 elements. You can use the index to access the `SeekBar` inside the array.

```
public class EqualizerForAudio extends Activity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    Integer id = 0;
    Equalizer equalizer;
    Integer max;

    // An array of SeekBar that contains 5 in total.
    SeekBar[] seekBars = new SeekBar[5];

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editSharedPreferences;

    SharedPreferences loadSharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.equalizer_);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editSharedPreferences = sharedPreferences.edit();

        loadSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", MODE_APPEND);

        id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id", 0);

        equalizer = new Equalizer(0, id);
        equalizer.setEnabled(true);

        max = (short) equalizer.getBandLevelRange()[1] - (short) equalizer.getBandLevelRange()[0];
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(max), 2000).show();

        // Init the SeekBar array.
        seekBars[0] = findViewById(R.id.equalizerSeekBar1);
        seekBars[1] = findViewById(R.id.equalizerSeekBar2);
        seekBars[2] = findViewById(R.id.equalizerSeekBar3);
        seekBars[3] = findViewById(R.id.equalizerSeekBar4);
        seekBars[4] = findViewById(R.id.equalizerSeekBar5);

        // Set SeekBar progress and equalizer based on value that saved in 
        // SharePreferences before.
        for (int i = 0; i < seekBars.length; i++) {
            int progress = loadSharedPreferences.getInt("seekBar" + i, 750);
            
            equalizer.setBandLevel((short) 0, (short) progress);
            
            seekBars[i].setMax(max);
            seekBars[i].setProgress(progress);
            seekBars[i].setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        // Access SeekBar based on their index in the array.
        for (int i = 0; i < seekBars.length; i++) {
            if (seekBars[i].getId() == seekBar.getId()) {
                equalizer.setBandLevel((short) i, (short) progress);
                
                editSharedPreferences.putInt("seekBar" + i, progress);
                editSharedPreferences.commit();
                
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar p1) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar p1) {
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have any problem while implementing, please let me know.

Comment: When I used seekbars[0] = findViewById(R.id.equalizerSeekBar1);   It is stopping.

Comment: Can you show the logcat where the error occurs?

Comment: But I am not doing it on Android Studio I am using AIDE. So sorry for that.

Comment: If you cannot use logcat, then try to comment out the code and run the app again. If success then remove the comment from a line of code, and keep repeating until the app not working. So we will determine which line of code which causes the error.

Comment: Yeah I have found the debugger in aide. It is showing that the error is in seekBar[0] = findViewById(R.id.equalizerSeekBar1);    Let me try what you have said

Comment: seekBars with ending `s`, like seekBars[0], seekBars[1]...seekBars[4]

Comment: In logcat its showing index array out of range

Comment: i am very very sorry I initialized the array as Seekbar[] seekBars = new SeekBar[4];   I should have given 5 instead of four. I apologise for that. Anyways thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EqualizerForAudio extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener
{
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    Integer id = 0;
    Equalizer equalizer;
    SeekBar b0,b1,b2,b3,b4;
    Integer b0s,b1s,b2s,b3s,b4s;
    Integer max;
    SeekBar[] s = new SeekBar[4];

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editSharedPreferences;

    SharedPreferences loadSharedPreferences;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.equalizer_);
    
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
        editSharedPreferences = sharedPreferences.edit();
        
        loadSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref",MODE_APPEND);
    
        id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id",0);
    
        equalizer = new Equalizer(0,id);
        equalizer.setEnabled(true);
    
        max = (short)equalizer.getBandLevelRange()[1] - (short)equalizer.getBandLevelRange()[0];
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(max),2000).show();

        equalizer.setBandLevel((short)0,(short)loadSharedPreferences.getInt("b0",750));
        equalizer.setBandLevel((short)1,(short)loadSharedPreferences.getInt("b1",750));
        equalizer.setBandLevel((short)2,(short)loadSharedPreferences.getInt("b2",750));
        equalizer.setBandLevel((short)3,(short)loadSharedPreferences.getInt("b3",750));
        equalizer.setBandLevel((short)4,(short)loadSharedPreferences.getInt("b4",750));
        
        b0s = loadSharedPreferences.getInt("b0",750);
        b1s = loadSharedPreferences.getInt("b1",750);
        b2s = loadSharedPreferences.getInt("b2",750);
        b3s = loadSharedPreferences.getInt("b3",750);
        b4s = loadSharedPreferences.getInt("b4",750);
        
        b0 = findViewById(R.id.equalizerSeekBar1);
        b1 = findViewById(R.id.equalizerSeekBar2);
        b2 = findViewById(R.id.equalizerSeekBar3);
        b3 = findViewById(R.id.equalizerSeekBar4);
        b4 = findViewById(R.id.equalizerSeekBar5);
    
        b0.setMax(max);
        b0.setProgress(loadSharedPreferences.getInt("b0",750));
    
        b1.setMax(max);
        b1.setProgress(loadSharedPreferences.getInt("b1",750));
    
        b2.setMax(max);
        b2.setProgress(loadSharedPreferences.getInt("b2",750));
    
        b3.setMax(max);
        b3.setProgress(loadSharedPreferences.getInt("b3",750));
    
        b4.setMax(max);
        b4.setProgress(loadSharedPreferences.getInt("b4",750));
    
        b0.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        b1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        b2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        b3.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        b4.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar p1, int p2, boolean p3)
    {
        if(p1.equals(b0)){
            equalizer.setBandLevel((short)0,(short)p2);
            editSharedPreferences.putInt("b0",p2);
        }else if(p1.equals(b1)){
            equalizer.setBandLevel((short)1,(short)p2);
            editSharedPreferences.putInt("b1",p2);
        }else if(p1.equals(b2)){
            equalizer.setBandLevel((short)2,(short)p2);
            editSharedPreferences.putInt("b2",p2);
        }else if(p1.equals(b3)){
            equalizer.setBandLevel((short)3,(short)p2);
            editSharedPreferences.putInt("b3",p2);
        }else if(p1.equals(b4)){
            equalizer.setBandLevel((short)4,(short)p2);
            editSharedPreferences.putInt("b4",p2);
        }
        editSharedPreferences.commit();
    }
    @Override public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar p1){}
    @Override public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar p1){}
}
```

Comment: I wanna make a list of seekbars and use it using their indexes